# Lead acid batteries replace by lithium in a golf cart

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am converting a golf cart from lead acid to lithium batteries, and when the accelerator is pushed hard from a standing stop, the cart kicks out.  I think I need a voltage regulator that limits the max voltage to 51 or so volts (it's a 48 volt system).  Or has anyone else had experience with this conversion?

This was my thinking.  When the cart is stopped, even for a minute or two, the batteries recover voltage to their current max - as high as 56 volts.  As you progress on a normal run the voltage drops, e.g. – going up a hill it drops from 53 volts to 48 volts and everything is working fine.

If, after a stop, you press the accelerator all the way it hits the system with the full, recovered voltage – 53 volts.  If you are gentle, the voltage is lower and the system likes it.  That is why I think a voltage regulator, in series, might work.

I tried one of the new lithium carts in our fleet and if you press the accelerator all the way, it takes maybe 5 seconds for the cart to feel all the power.  On my cart in AZ with the lead acids, if you push it hard the cart jumps to full acceleration right now.

Comment: Welcome. The pedal is sending signals to a power supply that drives the motors based on the pedal position. It may have adjustable torque settings to prevent 'jerky' starts. Adding large capacitor banks can help with fast initial acceleration, but quick acceleration means you charge the batteries more often..

Comment: I fixed your title. You're not converting lead-acid batteries to lithium (small L) which means modification of the batteries. You're replacing them.

Comment: You need to limit the current for limiting acceleration. The Motor controller may have a setting for this.